# How to get page occupied by graphs

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I am having trouble reproducing a series of graphs in RMardwon on the same page. Here is the dataset I am working with:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:6, Vid = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), Mus = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1), Rea = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), Ema = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0), SMS = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), tel = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
    rec = c(1, 0.16, 0.99, 0.95, 0.98, 0.92), MMT = c(53, 17.5, 
    48.5, 40, 46, 38), MM_levels = c("HMM", "IMM", "HMM", "IMM", 
    "HMM", "IMM")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`12` = 12L, `15` = 15L, 
`23` = 23L, `39` = 39L, `47` = 47L, `61` = 61L), class = "omit"))
```

Here the code that I have put in RMarkdown:

````
---
title: "x"
author: "x"
date: "x"
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos = "!", out.extra = "")
#install.packages('SetMethods')    
library(SetMethods)
x = df1$MMT
vector = c(ecdf(x)(11.29286), 0.50, ecdf(x)(40.19920))
color = c('blue', 'green', 'red')
labels = c('LMMs', 'IMMs', 'HMMs')
for(i in names(df1[c(2:7)])){
    #i <- paste0("~", i)
    print(xy.plot(x = i,
                  y = "rec",
                  data = as.data.frame(df1),
                  necessity = TRUE,
                  jitter = TRUE,
                  xlab = i,
                  ylab = "rec") + 
            geom_hline(yintercept=vector, color = color, linetype="dotted") +
            annotate(geom = "label", x = 0.50, y = vector, label = labels))
  }
```
````

Here is the output:

[image]

I would like that space in blank will be occupied by pictures. Would you any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Your document doesn't work as you posted it because `package("SetMethods")` is unrecognized.  When I replace that with `library("SetMethods")`, I get no output at all.  Could you please post code that gives the output you're showing?

Comment: That was an error on my end. Now the code should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the plots is too large for 2 plots to fit on a same page.

You can fix that using the `fig.height` chunk option, either locally as below, or within `knitr::opts_chunk$set` if you want it to apply to the whole document.

````
---
title: "x"
author: "x"
date: "x"
output:
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
---

```{r setup, fig.height = 4}
library(SetMethods)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos = "!", out.extra = "")

df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, 
                      Vid = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      Mus = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
                      Rea = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      Ema = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), 
                      SMS = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      tel = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
                      rec = c(1, 0.16, 0.99, 0.95, 0.98, 0.92), 
                      MMT = c(53, 17.5, 48.5, 40, 46, 38), 
                      MM_levels = c("HMM", "IMM", "HMM", "IMM", "HMM", "IMM")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 na.action = structure(c(`12` = 12L, `15` = 15L, `23` = 23L, 
                                         `39` = 39L, `47` = 47L, `61` = 61L), 
                                       class = "omit"))

x = df1$MMT
vector = c(ecdf(x)(11.29286), 0.50, ecdf(x)(40.19920))
color = c('blue', 'green', 'red')
labels = c('LMMs', 'IMMs', 'HMMs')

for(i in names(df1[c(2:7)])){
    #i <- paste0("~", i)
    print(xy.plot(x = i,
                  y = "rec",
                  data = as.data.frame(df1),
                  necessity = TRUE,
                  jitter = TRUE,
                  xlab = i,
                  ylab = "rec") + 
            geom_hline(yintercept=vector, color = color, linetype="dotted") +
            annotate(geom = "label", x = 0.50, y = vector, label = labels))
}
```
````

[image]